# DialogFlow NodeJs - Set Response Message after webhookClient.setFollowupEvent

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I am using https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs to create fulfillment webhook for dialogflow.
Currently I have intent that have 1 required parameter with prompt (so the agent will ask specific question for this parameter) and enable webhook call for this intent.

In the webhook, I check the parameter if that parameter is valid (call external api or something else), then I will trigger `setFollowupEvent` to move to other intent. But if the parameter is not valid, then I will trigger `setFollowupEvent` to return to this intent so the user should input it again. But I want to give the user a reason why that parameter is not valid.

The code is something like this

```
function registerUserStartHandler(agent) {
    let payload = request.body.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload;
    let senderDetail = getSenderDetail(payload);
    return isUserRegistered(senderDetail.senderId, senderDetail.platformType).then((res) => {
        if (res) {
            agent.add('User already registered, enter another user');
            //register_user_ask_user is this same intent (so I just returned to current intent if failed)
            agent.setFollowupEvent('register_user_ask_user');
        } else {
            agent.setFollowupEvent('register_user_ask_other_info');
        }
        return Promise.resolve();
    })
}
```

But, currently dialogflow will return to user the prompt message that I defined for that required parameter not the reason message.

How to replace this prompt message with my message from webhook?

Comment: Could you share some code so we can get a better idea of what's going on?

Comment: Actually I kinda temporary solve this with removing `agent.setFollowupEvent('register_user_ask_user');` but using context so next input from user still going to `register_user_ask_user` . And with this my message `User already registered, enter another user` appear